# How to implement scratch card animation in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to implement a scratch card animation in React Native.  What approaches can I take to achieve this result ?

I know there are some libraries out there that does the job but I'm mostly looking for some kind of discussion around the approach to take to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://github.com/romangua/react-native-scratch-view library to implement the scratch card for both iOS and android.

Refer this answer: [How to implement a scratch card / view in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655713/how-to-implement-a-scratch-card-view-in-react-native)

Comment: can you perhaps explain the approach the dev took to implement this lib?